# Popup Colour Menu in Qt

Tags: qt, colors, picker

In Qt, what's the best way to do a popup colour picker menu like this:

[image: http://www.servicehighway.com/docs/img/menu_transaction_context_color.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Qt doesn't have a QWidget class for this. You will need to write your own. Or use an existing one, like QColorPicker from [QtSolutions](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/solutions/lgpl/).